# Find number of array pairs (a,b) where abs(a-b) = k in O(n)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, hashtable

What is the number of pairs in an array where the difference of the two elements is a target number k? Brute force is trivial, start from each index and go through all upcoming indices. I need to do that in O(n). I know it's possible to do it using hash table but I can't get my hear around it.

Example:
[2,5,4,1,7,4], k=3
Here there are 5 pairs. (2,5), (4,1), (4,7), (1,4), (7,4)

I defined this problem as a simpler problem than Leetcode's Subarray Sum Equals K. I imaging the leetcode problem has the same solution except that it will be applied on the running sum array.

Comment: I'm not gonna answer this because I'm pretty sure you could find the solution elsewhere. The big intuition is that if you know k, you know for every element exactly what complements to look for (there are only like 2 options per entry, right?). Then, a preprocessing counter should be good enough? Big idea, at least.

Comment: If you're counting (4, 7) and (7, 4) then why other pairs like (2, 5) and (5, 2)?

Comment: The number 4 is there twice in the list which suggests that the 4-7 pair could be made in two ways. Hopefully the order of numbers in each pair doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a dictionary associating each instance of a number with its n-k value. This will have O(n) complexity.  Then run through the numbers and pair them with the list of corresponding numbers from the dictionary (also in O(n)):

```
numbers = [2,5,4,1,7,4]
k=3

numSet = dict()
for n in numbers: numSet.setdefault(n-k,[]).append(n) # O(n)
pairs  = [(n,m) for n in numbers for m in numSet.get(n,[])] #O(n)

print(pairs)

[(2, 5), (1, 4), (4, 7), (4, 7)]
```

*Given that numbers can repeat in the list, the actual complexity could be more than O(n) because the second part may yield more than n pairs (e.g. [3,6,3,6,3,6] produces 9 pairs).  Producing more than `n` results in O(n) is technically impossible but I guess the data provided is designed to avoid these extreme cases.*